# How to handle duplicates of closed questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

Last week, a new contributor asked, edited, and closed this question:

*[f_write output avi data is incorrect on STM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53534257/1212012)*

Today, almost the same question has been asked, only with slight differences:

*[Problem with MJPEG output data by f_write function (STM32)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53587882/1212012)*

I'm not sure if either question is good enough to remain open...

What should be done?

- Ask the author to delete the first question?
- Ask the author to delete the second question (and wait for the first reopening)?
- Flag the question to a moderator?

Note that I marked the new question as a duplicate of the older.

Comment: VtC as duplicate from the first one. You can do so even if the first one has no answers, beacuse the are from the same author.

Comment: If the second question appears to be an attempt to add details to the first question, you could suggest the poster to edit their first question instead of posting a new one (which is what's supposed to happen with closed/on hold questions).